# Two tomcat instances with different multicast addresses are grouped when using Jrockit

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, multicast, jrockit

I am trying to setup tomcat cluster upon Jrockit 1.6.0_45-b06, and faced with a problem.
It seems that Jrockit does not use Multicast address to group, I have setup 2 instances of tomcat in the same os, and give them difference multicast address, one is 228.0.0.3, the other is 228.0.0.4.
But they are grouped in the same cluster.

it will act as expected only if set different ports to them.

Is it a bug about Jrockit?

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems have been observed to ignore the address for multicast. Using different ports is the safest way to ensure separate clusters.

Comment: I have tested up, OpenJDK acted as expected on the same Linux.